# Elasticsearch search for a child and all his sibling documents grouped by parent

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to be able to submit a query which matches on child documents and returns the parent and all his child documents.

I have parent and child documents in my Elasticsearch index related through a join: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/parent-join.html?baymax=rec&rogue=rec-1&elektra=guide.

I have items divided into groups, each item in my index is a separate child document(NOTE: It's required to be able search children separately by different query, so I **can NOT use Nested objects**). The parent document contains a few meaningful fields like (name, sku, image) so it's required to get Parent along with its children.

I've achieved my requirements using following query:

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "has_child": {
      "type": "child",
      "query": {
        "has_parent": {
          "parent_type": "parent",
          "query": {
            "has_child": {
              "type": "child",
              "query": {
                "multi_match": {
                  "query": "NV1540JR",
                  "fields": [
                    "name",
                    "sku"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "inner_hits": {}
    }
  }
}
```

It's returns following result, which is exactly what I need:

```
{
    "took": 301,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 1,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": 1.0,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "my_index",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "Az9GEAT",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "id": "Az9GEAT",
                    "name": "Gold Calacatta 2.0",
                    "sku": "NV1540",
                    "my_join-field": "parent"
                },
                "inner_hits": {
                    "child": {
                        "hits": {
                            "total": {
                                "value": 2,
                                "relation": "eq"
                            },
                            "max_score": 1.0,
                            "hits": [
                                {
                                    "_index": "my_index",
                                    "_type": "_doc",
                                    "_id": "zx9EEAR",
                                    "_score": 1.0,
                                    "_routing": "Az9GEAT",
                                    "_source": {
                                        "id": "zx9EEAR",
                                        "name": "Gold Calacatta 12\" x 24\"",
                                        "sku": "NV1540M-2",
                                        "familyName": "Gold Calacatta 2.0",
                                        "familySku": "NV1540",
                                        "my_join-field": {
                                            "name": "child",
                                            "parent": "Az9GEAT"
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "_index": "my_index",
                                    "_type": "_doc",
                                    "_id": "Az9NEAT",
                                    "_score": 1.0,
                                    "_routing": "Az9GEAT",
                                    "_source": {
                                        "id": "Az9NEAT",
                                        "name": "Gold Calacatta 2.0, 24\" x 48\"",
                                        "sku": "NV1540JR",
                                        "familyName": "Gold Calacatta 2.0",
                                        "familySku": "NV1540",
                                        "my_join-field": {
                                            "name": "child",
                                            "parent": "Az9GEAT"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

In other way I could implement Application-side Join by making three different query calls(one to get all matching data, second to get siblings, third to get parents) and combining result in my Application. But not sure that it gonna be faster, cos of http request time and data processing time.

So, I'm a very newbee in elasticsearch and can't estimate how bad it is. How does it's affects the query performance? If there any other ways to get desired result? Or how my query could be improved? I'd be glad to hear any suggestions or thoughts! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ES it's a standard practice to retrieve a list of object ids & performs a second request to return a complete document set.

You can implement your logic using 2 queries

1. Request (1) all documents satisfying your child search criteria. Select only `child.id` & `child.parent_id` fields to ensure you load only index data, no document `_source` searched. Request will be relatively fast
2. In your application code determine unique list of `parent_ids` & `orphaned_child_ids`
3. Request (2) all documents satisfying criteria: `parent_id in parent_ids` OR `parent_id = NULL AND child_id in orphaned_child_ids`